# Gulp + docker.js, task integration

Tags: gulp

I'm new to the node ecosystem, has anyone tried to integrate [docker.js](http://jbt.github.io/docker/) as a [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task?

#### EDIT

`gulp-shell` does the job

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');
var shell  = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('docs', shell.task([
  'docker -i src/js -o docs -c manni -s yes -u -n --extras fileSearch,goToLine'
]));
```

Comment: I'm interested in doing this as well. It doesn't look like docker.js has any published node api docs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended-up just using the command-line api via `gulp-shell`:

```
var shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('docs', shell.task([
  'docker -o build/docs -i dev/js -n'
]));
```

Comment: Funny, I am looking to integrate [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) (as in, Dockerfiles, Docker images, and Docker containers) into the testing phase of my gulp process, and found this from google. Even though its a completely different "docker", this answer will also work for what I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: @MattKlein I am looking for the same, that is, notifications from gulp running within a container. Care to share your solution because I don't see how to do it without a an intermediate (http) service

Comment: This answer gave me the idea to just run docker commands from a wrapped command line. I was running this on Windows (and I suspect that you are, too, based on the need for an intermediate service) so that means my Docker instance was actually running in a VM hosted on my machine. The trick for me was to use `docker-machine env` to get the environment variables that the `docker` command expects (i.e. which IP address to communicate with). I then set those env variables to the shell instance and call my docker commands.